# How to get sha1 using cmd?

Tags: sha1, android-keystore

I tried a Lot of possibilities and I can't find the sha1 in my computer.
I tried this:

```
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore/mystore.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:915)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:415)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:408)



 /c/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.2/bin 

  keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey - 
  storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: after to many possibilities , i am found a solution go to vs code \ then "cd android" after that ".\gradlew signingReport" you well find the sha1 code

Answer (score 0):

After too many possibilities explored, I came to find a solution.

- Go to vs code,
- Then `cd android`
- After that `**.\gradlew** signingRepor`

You will find the sha1 code.